# Can we delete the .ova file after importing it in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox on my MacBook and downloaded the Kali Linux .ova file to use as a virtual machine. However, I am running out of storage and the .ova file is taking up almost 4 GB of storage. Can I delete the .ova file now that I have imported it in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You can delete the `.ova` file from your OS if you're sure the VM imported successfully